# Can you make strawberry extract at home?

Tags: strawberries, vodka

I know you can make vanilla extract, using vodka and vanilla pods. But can you replace the vanilla pods by pieces of strawberry? I'm not sure whether the vodka would absorb the strawberry flavour, but if it works, I think I could give some desserts that extra punch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some essences and herbs need alcohol to be extracted, but not strawberries.

Extracts from berries can be made in the pressure cooker, to later turn into syrups or jellies.  Here's a step-by-step photos and instructions on how to do it.
http://www.hippressurecooking.com/2011/08/blackberry-italian-soda-from-your.html

You could then mix the syrup with vodka, instead of mineral water as in the recipe, to make a strawberry cocktail.